# What on earth am I?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

*I do not get around much, but I am heavily debated,*

*You might see me with your naked eyes, but my shadow exposes my disguise,*

*The further away from me you are, the less I seem real,*

*Your attraction towards me depends on where you are from, but it does not seem to matter a great deal,*

*Even the others around me in the room make me out to be different from what I claim to be.*

Comment: Probably an Euclid-class SCP

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**What on earth am I?**

> Flatness (specifically, a flat Earth)

I do not get around much, but I am heavily debated,

> The theory of a flat Earth isn't very popular, but adherents are known for vehemently defending it. (Also, a pun on a*round*.)

You might see me with your naked eyes, but my shadow exposes my disguise,

> The Earth appears flat from the perspective of just looking around on the ground, however the Earth's shadow against the Moon reveals that it is curved.

The further away from me you are, the less I seem real,

> The higher up you travel, the clearer the curvature is (first the horizon, then the view from outer space)

Your attraction towards me depends on where you are from, but it does not seem to matter a great deal,

> I haven't been able to find a source suggesting that people from certain places tend to believe in a flat Earth, but the word *attraction* in this clue makes me wonder if this has to do with gravity.

Even the others around me in the room make me out to be different from what I claim to be.

> No idea... it's a stretch but artificial satellites ("around [the Earth] in the room") make the Earth out to be round?

---

### OP's explanations:

**What on earth am I?**

> Flat Earth (theory).
>  The "earth" in the title was a small hint

I do not get around much, but I am heavily debated,

You might see me with your naked eyes, but my shadow exposes my disguise,

> Although the Earth's shadow on the moon indeed *exposes* a flaw in Flat Earth theory, the implied reference was about different shadows at different times of the day. [Video explanation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3EspZtA7C3o&feature=youtu.be&t=3m53s).

The further away from me you are, the less I seem real,

Your attraction towards me depends on where you are from, but it does not seem to matter a great deal,

> If the earth was flat, the center of gravity would be in the middle. So if you lived away from the center of the Earth gravity would pull you towards the center (sideways). But since this is not the case, living in different places *does not seem to matter a great deal*. [Video explanation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1xwmqEUMWRI&feature=youtu.be&t=15s)

Even the others around me in the room make me out to be different from what I claim to be.

> Here, *room* is another word for space. And *the others* are other planets. If all the other planets are spheres, but the Earth is not, that would make no cosmological sense and would make everything go out of balance.

Comment: Well done! Do you mind if I add an extra explanation to the last 2 sentences?

Comment: I'd assume "the others in the room" are other planets in space, which are "round", but look like flat circles through a telescope.

Comment: @SirExotic go ahead :) (though I'm new here and don't know site conventions for this kind of thing) Thanks for the fun puzzle!

Comment: Thank you, it was fun to see everyone's answers! I added additional explanations below your answers, I think you'll enjoy them :)

Answer (score 13):

Are you

> the past

I do not get around much, but I am heavily debated,

> Most of us live in the present but we talk a lot about the past.

You will not see me with your naked eyes, but my shadow exposes my disguise,

> We do not see the past but the shadow of the past (not sure but I think I heard this expression somewhere)

The further away from me you are, the less I seem real,

> As the time goes our memory from the past get blurry and it doesn't seem as real

Your attraction towards me depends on where you are from, but it does not seem to matter a great deal,

> Some regret the past more than other. The country we are from doesn't matter but our previous situation does.

Even the others around me in the room make me out to be different from what I 
claim to be.

> We see the past differently than it really was. Everyone remembers the past differently .

Comment: Your answer was so good I almost wish it was correct myself, but unfortunately it isn't.

Answer (score 4):

It could be an

> X-ray

As,
*I do not get around much, but I am heavily debated,*

> Not a usual/frequently used one. But people debate that we should not get ourselves exposed to X-rays frequently, lest it would be problematic.

*You will not see me with your naked eyes, but my shadow exposes my disguise,*

> We cannot see X-ray with naked eye, but we can see its casted shadows on films.

*The further away from me you are, the less I seem real,*

> It demands the to be X-rayed objects to stay as much closer as possible

*Your attraction towards me depends on where you are from, but it does not seem to matter a great deal,*

> Only patients/ people interested in medical check ups use X-ray based equipment...but not all.

*Even the others around me in the room make me out to be different from what I claim to be.*

> The equipment in an X-ray room cannot be linked to the (As by a layman)production of X-rays( a little stretch over here!)

Comment: Not bad, but not close enough!

Answer (score 3):

Are you...?

> Gravity

I do not get around much, but I am heavily debated,

> Gravity is not a "thing to move around", but a force related to bodies' weights («heavily»).

You might see me with your naked eyes, but my shadow exposes my disguise,

> Not sure about this one.

The further away from me you are, the less I seem real,

> Gravity's magnitude is inversely proportional to the square of the distance between two bodies.

Your attraction towards me depends on where you are from, but it does not seem to matter a great deal,

> In each point on Earth, the altitude varies, so does the distance to the Earth's center. This way, the attraction depends on the location, but the exact magnitude's value doesn't vary much on Earth.

Even the others around me in the room make me out to be different from what I claim to be.

> In a certain perspective, the greater the number of close bodies there are is at a region, the greater the number of forces there will be, messing up with each others' resulting force. So, in effect, other forces around make gravity appear to be different than it is (for instance, magnetic force can make gravity apparently "disappear").

Comment: Also not a bad attempt, but not quite it.

Comment: Happy to try, still :)

Answer (score 3):

Are you

> The future?

I do not get around much, but I am heavily debated,

> People predict what will happen in days to come.

You might see me with your naked eyes, but my shadow exposes my disguise,

> You will see the future eventually, but there are also things that can lead to certain events(Like after an earthquake you may expect after shocks).

The further away from me you are, the less I seem real,

> The father away from things you are like when you are a kid, you might not know what profession you want when you become an adult, but with age and the closer it gets it may become clearer.

Your attraction towards me depends on where you are from, but it does not seem to matter a great deal,

> People may not think of the present as much as the future.

Even the others around me in the room make me out to be different from what I claim to be.

> People may try and tell what the future will hold, but it might really be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Best I have is

> The Sun

I do not get around much, but I am heavily debated,

> The Sun doesn't move but its been debated as the center of the solar system/the universe in history

You might see me with your naked eyes, but my shadow exposes my disguise,

> You *can* look at the bare sun, but looking at it indirectly (during an eclipse) is safer

Your attraction towards me depends on where you are from, but it does not seem to matter a great deal,

> Some people, like people from warmer climates, typically enjoy spending time in the sun/tanning more

Even the others around me in the room make me out to be different from what I claim to be.

> You're surrounded by planets, which are very different from the sun as a star

Comment: Not the answer, but I do really like your creativity with the explanations :)

Answer (score 1):

I was surprised at OPs intended answer -- I could have sworn it was

> Dark matter

I do not get around much, but I am heavily debated

> Dark matter is certainly heavily debated. It interacts weakly (if at all) with ordinary matter, so in that sense it certainly doesn't get around much.

You might see me with your naked eyes, but my shadow exposes my disguise

> "See" is pretty debatable, but your naked eyes presumably encounter dark matter all the time, without actually registering them. The "shadow" of dark matter is the gravitational force it emits, which is the only thing that exposes its disguise as nothing.

The further away from me you are, the less I seem real

> The further away you are, the less you feel the effects of its gravity, and so the less you have any direct evidence it exists

Your attraction towards me depends on where you are from, but it does not seem to matter a great deal,

> Gravitational attraction depends on relative location. And it doesn't matter a great deal since dark matter interacts so weakly, or perhaps because its gravity still isn't conclusive evidence that it exists (as opposed to some other effect causing the gravitational imbalance).

Even the others around me in the room make me out to be different from what I claim to be.

> Many physicists don't believe in dark matter, and favor a modified Newtonian dynamics / entropic gravity explanation instead.

Comment: I actually thought my riddle was too specific and would get no attempts until someone got it. On the contrary, I've seen many creative answers :)